# allow wordpress to write to files

Tags: permissions, apache2, wordpress

I have been having problems recently with an Ubuntu 16.04 x64 VPS when trying to get a web server up and running. I am using `apache2` as the web server as I only really have experience in that - will most likely move to `nginx` soon, due to hearing that it has better performance.

I'm using WordPress and developing a theme for it. My first problem is when I'm attempting to install WordPress and I get the following error:

> Sorry, but I can't write the `wp-config.php' file.

This confused me, but soon found this answer ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358322)) that never helped at all.

I then read on the WordPress Codex about File Permissions ([here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress)). I changed all of the files and folders with the following commands ([link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/5666482)) - again, never worked.

So, I made all of the files manually and now I want to change the permalink structure..... WordPress needs writing permissions. How can I fix this error:

> If your .htaccess file were [writable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions), we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all.

and get this site up and running successfully?

TL;DR... I need write permissions for my WordPress site. How can I complete my objective?

Comment: Hi! How it worked out with nginx? Doyou still have permissions problems with nginx?

Answer (score -1):

I also have an Apache/Ubuntu/Wordpress server, so hopefully this will work for you.

When first setting up your server, you can open up the permissions like so:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

That should take care of the permissions issue. After initial setup however, you will want to lock them back down.

#### Warning: It is EXTREMELY important that you do not leave the permissions as 777 after initial setup! That would allow anyone write access to your server!

Comment: To make editing easier you can use `sudo chown -R <your username>:www-data /var/www/html` instead and not using chmod at all. this way still the only ones having access are root,you and www-data ;)

Comment: Understandably, I can see why you would do this - I have done something similar before. Although, I wish for WordPress to be able to download plugins, or write to new files, or to create files *at any time*. So, therefore, this method cannot be used. I shall wait and see if I get any more responses - if not, I'm afraid this will do.

Comment: @JoshMurray - Oh, in that case you just need to change the perms for a few specific directories. I need to go somewhere right now, but when I get back I can update my answer regarding that :)

Comment: @AndroidDev: Any update regarding this problem? Cheers.

Comment: @JoshMurray - Oh, my apologies, I completely forgot! I'll update tomorrow as soon as I have a chance to test on my server.

Comment: @JoshMurray Ok so to allow plugin and theme updates you'll need to do `sudo chown -R /var/www/html/wp-content www-data:www-data`

Comment: As noted above in my question, I have already changed all of the file and directory permissions as well as changing the groups to the one Apache uses, hence meaning, this doesn't work in my case. Hopefully, it does for someone else, though.

Comment: @JoshMurray *shrug* All I can say is that works on my Apache + Ubuntu + WordPress server.....

Comment: Please edit this answer to remove the `chmod 777 ` so someone doesn't blindly copy paste this.